# inherited_resources - best practices for missing parent model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, inherited-resources

Maybe you have seen/read the [Railscast/Asciicast about subdomains in Rails  3](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3). I'd like you to ask about best practices on how to implement an application behavior when the parent (in this article: "blog") is not found. Let me explain.

```
blog1.example.com/articles # it's normal situation
example.com/articles # abnormal situation.
```

In the second example no blog to find, but articles's routes are still available. I know, I can use something like this ...

```
def rescue_action(exception)
  case exception
    when ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      return redirect_to blogs_path, :status => :moved_permanently
  end
  super
end
```

... but is it the "Rails way"? Any idea/comment on this?

Answer (score 0):

What I did in this case, was to restrict the routing based on subdomain or no subdomain. In that case, you can easily have routes that only work on subdomains, resulting in a routing error (404) if someone tries to access that same route without a subdomain.

So for example:

#### routes.rb

```
Backend::Application.routes.draw do

  constraints AppDomainRoutes.new do

    # signup paths
    get   "/signup" => "accounts#new", as: "signup"
    post  "/signup" => "accounts#create", as: "signup"

    # root
    root to: "accounts#new"
  end

  constraints AccountDomainRoutes.new do

    # password reset paths
    get   "/reset_password/:password_reset_token" => "reset_passwords#edit", as: "reset_user_password"
    put   "/reset_password/:password_reset_token" => "reset_passwords#update", as: "reset_user_password"

    # websites
    resources :websites

    # root
    root to: "websites#new"
  end

  # request password reset paths
  get   "/reset_password" => "reset_passwords#new", as: "reset_password_request"
  post  "/reset_password" => "reset_passwords#create", as: "reset_password_request"

  # login paths
  get "/login"   => "sessions#new",      as: "login"
  post "/login"  => "sessions#create",   as: "login"

  # logout paths
  get "/logout"    => "sessions#destroy",  as: "logout"
  delete "/logout" => "sessions#destroy",  as: "logout"


end
```

And then in lib/routes:

#### app_domain_routes.rb

```
class AppDomainRoutes
  def matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.blank? || request.subdomain == "www"
  end
end
```

#### account_domain_routes.rb

```
class AccountDomainRoutes
  def matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www"
  end
end
```

Now, `/signup` is only accessible from the main application domain *www.mydomain.com or mydomain.com* and `/websites/new` is only accessible from **.mydomain.com*. But `/login` is still accessible in both situations, for convenience sake.

Obviously this doesn't solve the issue of visiting `invalid.mydomain.com` when `invalid` in fact is not an account in the database.

For this you go back to the `application_controller.rb` and handle redirection there, like this:

#### application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :redirect_unknown_account

  private

  # returns current subdomain (account.subdomain) or nil
  def account_subdomain
    @account_subdomain ||= request.subdomain if request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www"
  end

  def current_account
    @current_account ||= Account.find_by_username(account_subdomain) if account_subdomain
  end

  def redirect_unknown_account
    if account_subdomain && ! current_account
      redirect_to signup_url(host: app_domain), alert: "This account does not exist."
    end
  end

  def account_domain
    @account_domain ||= "#{current_account.username}.#{app_domain}" if current_account
  end

  def app_domain
    @app_domain ||= "mydomain.com"
  end

end
```